# How to remove the existence of a div with fadeout and delay functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout

I have a situation here that i have a common success message div coming on top of the page. It has a functionality as below:

```
function showSuccessMessage(messageType) {
                var messageParam = 'success-message.' + messageType;
                var successMessage = messageParam;
                // Show the success message
                $('.success-message').text(successMessage).hide().fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
            };
```

If user does a success submit and then within 5 seconds, he is able to an another submit which again calls the above method, the previous data with message is fading out and after it completes then the second one fires so it looks kind of unrealistic and odd.

I need to stop fading and clear the div data and show the latest one and overriding the previous message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for that, like this:

```
 $('.success-message').stop(true,true).hide().text(successMessage).fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
```

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/530d8)